# How to hide multiple elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
   <title> 
       Hide or show HTML elements using 
       visibility property in JavaScript 
   </title> 

   <style> 
           .container { 
           height: 80px; 
           width: 250px; 
           border: 2px solid black; 
           background-color: green; 
           color: white; 
   </style> 
</head> 

<body> 
   <center> 
       <div class="container"> 
           <h1>Number of Child</h1> 
       </div> 

       <p class="container2"> 
           Click the buttons to show 
           or hide the green box 
       </p> 
 <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female"  onclick="showElement()"
        checked>
           <label for="female">Female</label>
        <label for="male">Male</label>
         <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" onclick="hideElement()">  

   </center> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
       function showElement() { 
           element = document.querySelector(".container"); 
           element = document.querySelector(".container2"); 

           element.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
       } 

       function hideElement() { 
           element = document.querySelector(".container"); 
           element = document.querySelector(".container2"); 

           element.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
       } 
   </script> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Okay so here's the simple code, I want to target 2 elements, which are : ".container"and ".container2"

but the method `document.querySelector` only choose one, how can I fix this ?

Link to the code :
https://jsfiddle.net/7cgmq0tx/

Comment: `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: I've already try it, didn't worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second `querySelector` overrides first one, you should use two variables:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
       function showElement() { 
           element1 = document.querySelector(".container"); 
           element2 = document.querySelector(".container2"); 

           element1.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
           element2.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
       } 

       function hideElement() { 
           element1 = document.querySelector(".container"); 
           element2 = document.querySelector(".container2"); 

           element1.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
           element2.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
       } 
   </script>
```

Comment: Oh yeah indeed, the solution was basic, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to make element equal something twice in the same block, javascript will instinctively make only the last one specified be true when the code is run. Which is why it only affects one element when you click the buttons. Try this instead:

```
function showElement() { 
           element = document.querySelector(".container"); 
           element2 = document.querySelector(".container2"); 

           element.style.visibility = 'visible';
           element2.style.visibility = 'visible';
       } 

       function hideElement() { 
           element = document.querySelector(".container"); 
           element2 = document.querySelector(".container2"); 

           element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
           element.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
       }
```